# Mysqli multi query PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, multi-query

I want to use php mysqli function, to query this:

```
SET @rownum = 0, @rank = 1, @prev_val = NULL;
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row,
    @rank := IF(@prev_val!=score,@rownum,@rank) AS rank,
    userid,
    @prev_val := score AS score
FROM (
    SELECT userid, sum(amount) as score 
    from leads WHERE date(time) >= '2013-08-15'
    group by userid
) exodus_entries 
 ORDER BY rank asc LIMIT 0,100;
```

I tried using the mysqli_query(link, query); function, but no luck, any help?

Comment: Try using [mysqli::multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead because your query is actually multiple statements

Comment: I am trying this: 
$query = mysqli_multi_query($cxn,$sqll);
$result = mysqli_store_result($cxn);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo $row[1] . "<br>";
}

But mysqli_fetch_row returns error.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: in that case, show your (php) code. And you can already try changing `mysqli_multi_query(.....);` into  `mysqli_multi_query(.....) or die (mysqli_error());`. This should tell you if you have any mysql errors that would otherwise be silently ignored.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use multi-query, and you risk [security problems](http://xkcd.com/327) whenever you use multi-query.

The values for you user variables @rownum, @rank, @prev_val will remain in effect for the second query, as long as you run both query in the same connection.

So just run `mysqli_query("SET ...");` and then run `mysqli_query("SELECT...");` separately.  It's much simpler to do this, and avoids at least one security risk.

Regarding your error:

```
mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

*Always* check the return value of mysqli_query().  It will return **false** if there's an error.  And of course you can't run `mysqli_fetch_row(false);`

Comment: Awesome.  This is documented almost nowhere on any APIs or forums.  I don't know if this is an "obvious" solution, but I've been searching for over 2 days for this solution.

Comment: @Michael, read the first paragraph of this manual page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html It doesn't literally say that setting a user-variable lasts for the rest of the session, but that's what happens, and it's sure easy to test if you are in doubt.